# Clone element in a DOM and change the attribute while reusing it in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, clone

My code is given below

```
;(function(window){

    var description_window= document.querySelector('.mg_post_description');

    var $headings= document.querySelectorAll('.mg_blog_main_content h3');

    for (var i = $headings.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        description_window.append($headings[i].cloneNode(true));
    };

})(window);
```

Can I change the h3 collected from the 'blog_main_contents' to 'p' tags in the target div.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through `h3`'s child nodes and append it to new paragraph element:

```
var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
var headingChildren = $headings[i].cloneNode(true).childNodes;
for (var j = 0; j < headingChildren.length; j++) {
  paragraph.appendChild(headingChildren[j]);
}
description_window.append(paragraph);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `insertAdjecentHtml` in this example didnt really need jquery.

```
for (let i = $headings.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
   description_window.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin","<p>"+ $headings[i].innerHTML + "</p>");
};
```

Here is a working **[Example](https://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/jmGvgz)**.